# want to optimize a "phone number generator" code with loop deduction

Tags: python-3.x, performance, loops, for-loop, optimization

Description of program:

1.makes unique random phone numbers based on how many you want it to i mean: if you pass 100 it makes 100 phone numbers.

2.creates text files based on the range you pass to it, i mean: if you need 100 text files containing 100 unique phone numbers either unique comparing to each number within or the other to be made forthcoming text files.

**meanwhile it creates phone numbers sorts the phone numbers like below if it makes sense:**

**This format to expect in the text files :**

1. - 1909911304
2. - 1987237347

........... and so on.............

This is the method responsible to do so:

(**Note: I use make_numbers method as construction of operation, Actually num_doc_amount should be used.**)

```
    def make_numbers(self):
        """dont use this method:this method supports num_doc_amount method"""
        # sorry for this amount of loops it was inevitable to make the code work
        for number_of_files in range(self.amount_numbs):
            # this loop maintains the pi_digits.txt making(txt)
            number_of_files += 1
            if number_of_files == self.amount_files:
                sys.exit()
            for phone_numbers in range(self.amount_numbs):
                # This loop maintains the amount of phone numbers in each pi_digits.txt
                file = open(f"{self.directory}\\{number_of_files}.{self.format}", 'w')
                for numbers in range(self.amount_numbs):
                    # This loop is parallel to the previous one and
                    # writes that each number is which one from the
                    # whole amount of numbers
                    file.write(f"{numbers + 1}. - {self.first_fourz}{choice(nums)}"
                               f"{choice(nums)}{choice(nums)}{choice(nums)}"
                               f"{choice(nums)}{choice(nums)}{choice(nums)}\n")

    def num_doc_amount(self):
        """first make an instance and then you can use this method."""
        os.mkdir(f"{self.directory}")  # makes the folder
        for num_of_txt_files in range(self.amount_files):
            # This loop is for number of text files.
            num_of_txt_files += 1
            self.make_numbers()
```

Note That:

1.**The only problem i have is with those parallel loops going with each other, i don't know if i can make the code simplified.(please let me know if it can be simplified.)**

2.**The code works and has no error.**

*if there is any way to make this code simplified please help me.**Thank you.***

Comment: What's `nums`? -- Although you say _makes unique random phone numbers_, the code has no provision that the written phone numbers are unique.

Comment: sorry @Armali ,nums is a variable that a  list containing words from 0 to 9 is assigned to it before the class definition, i missed to include that in the code.please if you know a way let me know.`nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: @Armali is there any way to omit even one of these loops, because... you know, each has a specific thing to do, The First one has to loop based on the number of files wanted to make phone nmbers, The Second one is for generating a kind of counting the phone numbers withing each txt file and the Third Loop has to loop  to generate phone numbers. Is It normal ??!! or phythonic, or its a messy code containing a lot of irregularities.@Armali

Comment: How the code can be improved depends on whether you require the phone numbers to be unique, and if so, whether they must be unique only within one file, or over all files. You'd first have to answer this.

Comment: @Armali , yes i want all the phone numbers to be unique and this uniqueness should not be confined only to one file, all phone numbers generated for each file must be unique and must be differentiated comparing to the other txt files that the generated phone numbers are stored in.

Comment: have you come across `codereview.stackexchange.com`? That tends to be the place to post working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.The only problem i have is with those parallel loops going with each other, i don't know if i can make the code simplified.(please let me know if it can be simplified.)

Even if that's not the *only problem*, indeed there are unnecessarily many loops in the above code. It takes not more than two: one loop over the files, one loop over the numbers; see below.

> 2.The code works and has no error.

That's false, since you *want all the phone numbers to be unique*. As said, the code has no provision that the written phone numbers are unique. To achieve this, it's easiest to generate all unique numbers once at the start.

```
    def num_doc_amount(self):
        """first make an instance and then you can use this method."""
        os.mkdir(self.directory)    # makes the folder
        un = sample(range(10**7), self.amount_files*self.amount_numbs)  # all the unique numbers
        # This loop is for number of text files:
        for num_of_txt_file in range(self.amount_files):
            with open("%s/%s.%s"%(self.directory, 1+num_of_txt_file, self.format), 'w') as file:
                # This loop maintains the amount of phone numbers in each .txt:
                for number in range(self.amount_numbs):
                    # writes one number from the whole amount of numbers
                    file.write("%s. - %s%07d\n" %(1+number, self.first_fourz, un.pop()))
```